# Long exact homology sequence in singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand/develop the proof of the following theorem:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1.
Suppose $(C_*, c_*), (D_*, d_*), (E_*, e_*)$ are $R$-chain complexes and $i_*: C* \rightarrow D_*, q_*: D_* \rightarrow E_*$ are chain maps. Let
\begin{align*}
0 \rightarrow C_{*} \stackrel{i_{*}}\rightarrow D_{*} \stackrel{q_{*}}\rightarrow E_{*} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
be a short exact sequence of $R$-chain complexes, i.e. 
\begin{align*}
0 \rightarrow C_{n} \stackrel{i_{n}}\rightarrow D_{n} \stackrel{q_{n}}\rightarrow E_{*} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
is exact for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then there exists a natural long exact sequence of homologies
\begin{align*}
\dotsc &\stackrel{\partial_{n+1}}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_n(C_*) \stackrel{\mathcal{H}_n(i_*)}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_n(D_*) \stackrel{\mathcal{H}_n(q_*)}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_n(E_*)
\stackrel{\partial_{n}}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{n-1}(C_*) 
 \stackrel{\mathcal{H}_{n-1}(i_*)}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{n-1}(D_*) \stackrel{\mathcal{H}_{n-1}(q_*)}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{n-1}(E_*)\\ &\stackrel{\partial_{n-1}}\rightarrow \dotsc
\end{align*}
**Proof:** Define $\partial_{n+1}: \mathcal{H}_{n+1}(E_*) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{n+1}(C_*)$ as follows:

Let $x \in Ker(e_{n+1})$ be cycle and $[x]\in \mathcal{H}_{n+1}(E_*)$ the corresponding homology class.
Now, since $q_{n+1}$ is surjective there exists $y \in D_{n+1}$ with $q_{n+1}(y)=x$ and it holds that
\begin{align*}
&q_n(d_{n+1}(y)) = e_{n+1}(q_{n+1}(y)) = e_{n+1}(y) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \exists z \in C_n \text{ with } i_n(z) = d_{n+1}(y)\\
& i_{n-1}(c_n(z)) = d_n(i_n(z)) = d_n(d_{n+1}(y)) = 0 \\
& \Rightarrow c_n(z) = 0 \text{ (since $i_{n-1}$ is injective)}. 
\end{align*}
Thus, $z\in Ker(c_n)$. So, define $\partial_{n+1}([x]) := [z]\in Ker(c_n)/Im(c_{n+1})$.
What is left to show, is that
(1) $\partial_{n+1}([x])$ is well-defined and a $R$-homomorphism
(2) The sequence of homologies is indeed exact.

Unfortunately, I am not able to show even the first part:
Let $v \in [x]$, so $x-v \in Im(e_{n+1})$. Now, construct $\tilde{z}$ (as above) such that $\partial_{n+1}([v]) = \tilde{z}$. To show is that $[\tilde{z}]-[z] \in Im(c_{n+1})$. Now I don't know how to proceed.

Is there anyone who could help me?

Cheers,
quizzle